# files uploaded by ftp_put are becoming shortcuts on the server

Tags: php, file, ftp

```
$audiofname = $_FILES['audiofile']['name'];
$local_file = $_FILES['audiofile']['tmp_name'];
$ftpdir = 'domain/path/to/file/';

ftp_chdir($conn_id, $ftpdir);
ftp_put($conn_id, $audiofname, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);
```

every uploaded file's size is becoming 4kb, but filename and extension are correct.

Comment: What do you mean by *"becoming shortcuts"*? Why are you using ASCII mode? Did you check a size of `$local_file`? Can you correctly upload the file using a standalone FTP client? Show us a verbose log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes it works fine from ftp client.  i'm using ASCII because it is used here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: That's a pretty bad reason. You are uploading binary file (audio stream), so use binary mode `FTP_BINARY`.